# mysqli php table names with hyphen or space

Tags: php, mysqli, names

The website is intended to display certain laws/rules by jurisdiction.

There is a simple mysqli query that finds the counties and then displays the county names on screen with this:

```
echo "><a href=\"index.php?sel_subj=" . urlencode($subject["county_name"]) . "\">
{$subject["county_name"]}</a></li>";
```

Then you click on a county name (embedded with the link) and a mysqli query is supposed to look up a table with that county name and get all the jurisdictions within that county.

```
if (isset($_GET['sel_subj'] )){
  $query2 = "SELECT * FROM $sel_subj";
  $result2 = $mysqli2->query($query2) or die($mysqli2->error.__LINE__);
    while ($subject = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
      echo "<li";
      echo "><a href=\"index.php?sel_page=" . urlencode($subject["muni_name"]);
      echo "&sel_subj=" . urlencode($sel_subj). "\">
      {$subject["muni_name"]}</a></li>";
    }
}
```

The problem is that some county names include a space or a hyphen.  So when I click on the counties that have a hyphen or space, there is an error.

I get this error when there is a hyphen (example: Miami-Dade):
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-Dade' at line 173

And this error when there is a space (example: Palm Beach):
Table 'florida.palm' doesn't exist73

If the county is just a string without any special characters, then the jurisdictions are displayed no problem.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to provide a hacker with a hole of **THAT** size?

Comment: where do you set the value of $sel_subj

Comment: @Anigel Maybe global vars are on. Which, user2436671, you should probable take care of.

Comment: @MaX It's possible, but unlikely as register globals has been disabled by default since before the mysqli functions were included.

Comment: True. He says he gets good results for names not containing special characters, so the variable obviously has a value, just giving it a guess.

Answer (score 0):

your database structure is wrong.

It have to be **ONE** table where country being a field among other columns.

So, the code have to be like this

```
if (isset($_GET['sel_subj'] )){
  $query = "SELECT * FROM documents WHERE country = ?";
  $stmt  = $mysqli->prepare($query) or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
  $stmt->bind_param('s',$_GET['sel_subj']);
  $stmt->execute();
  $res = $stmt->get_result();
  while ($subject = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
      echo "<li";
      echo "><a href=\"index.php?sel_page=" . urlencode($subject["muni_name"]);
      echo "&sel_subj=" . urlencode($sel_subj). "\">
      {$subject["muni_name"]}</a></li>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to wrap your county name if it contains character like that. BUT, you also need to sanitize your input:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM `".mysqli_real_escape_string ($sel_subj)."`";
```

**EDIT:**

Also, you should look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to avoid sql injection.

You should further sanitize your input by limiting the table names that can be defined to those containing county information.

Comment: Please nooooo! Neither mysqli_real_escape_string not prepared statement could help against injection here

Comment: I'm just saying... With his specific need for dynamic table names, where table names may contain spaces, this is what you have to do. I'm not saying it's a great solution, but it's what he needs and asks for.

Comment: thanks for the input. ive seen lots of people talk about sql injection and prepared statements, but not sure how to build with those things in mind.  Im just taking code snippets from books, webpages and stringing together to develop this site.  Do you know of any good tutorials or explanations of these things?

Comment: You can look at the link i posted in my answer to learn how to use prepared statement. There is a lot of different stuff to read about sql injection. Just go to Google and search for it, you'll find lots of material. In short, it's all about preventing users from executing sql inside your sql statements, typically by using input directly from forms.

Comment: How do I simply list tables from a DB using prepared statements?

I have this code now, but it doesn't work...

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SHOW TABLES FROM subjects");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    while($stmt->fetch()):
    $table_name=ucwords($row[0]);
    echo "<li><a href=\"index.php?sel_subj=" 
. urlencode($table_name) . "\">{$table_name}</a></li>";
    endwhile;

Comment: Is `subjects` actually your database name? If you're not sure, try with just `SHOW TABLES`. Also, you use `store_result ` but not e.g. `mysqli_data_seek`, if you don't need it, just remove it. There are other things that could be improved, but you should probably create a new question for that.