# Hyphen in php database table name

Tags: php, mysql

I'm experiencing the exact same problem as this guy: [mysqli php table names with hyphen or space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837568/mysqli-php-table-names-with-hyphen-or-space) but I don't completely understand it because it's so much code. Can someone pls look at my code and tell me what I have to change in my code to solve the problem:

```
<form action="dienstencheque_dienstencheques_huishoudhulp_poetsvrouw_kuisvrouw_.php" method="get">
<?php
extract($_GET);
mysql_connect("localhost", "phpgebruiker", "php");
mysql_select_db("poetsco");
$gemeente = "SELECT naam FROM $provincie ORDER BY naam ASC";
$resultaat = mysql_query($gemeente) or die("FOUT" . mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error());
$rij = mysql_fetch_array($resultaat);
  while ($rij) { ?>
   <a href="dienstencheque_dienstencheques_huishoudhulp_poetsvrouw_kuisvrouw_.php?gemeente=<?php print $rij["naam"] ?>"> Huishoudhulp in <?php print $rij["naam"] ?></a><br>
<?php $rij = mysql_fetch_array($resultaat);} ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Please tell us what your problem actually is instead of just linking to another question saying that's what your problem is.

Comment: `extract($_GET)`? If this is new code, I strongly urge you to not do that.

Comment: Thx for your responses, I red in the instructions that it was not allowed to pose a question that was already posed. Why is not good to use extract($_GET)?

Answer (score 0):

If the table name defined in `$provincie` contains a hyphen you will have to quote it in your SQL query:

```
$gemeente = "SELECT naam FROM `$provincie` ORDER BY naam ASC";
```

Comment: Thx for your response. I tested it but it only made it worse because now also the table names without hyphens give me the same kind of error. I also tested it with " but that just turned the problem the ones with hyphen are good then but those without give an error.